# Element is not taking focus Javascript

Tags: javascript, focus, keyevent, onfocus, tabindex

I have  a list whose structure looks like this

```
<ul>
   <li tabindex =0> hello <li>
   <li> hi </li>
   <li> bye </li>
   <li> goodbye </li>
</ul.
```

When the focus is on hello and I press keydown the focus should move to hi. I do this programmatically by setting the focus.
I have a listener set on the list which track the key events

```
handleKeyevent (e){
    if(e.item.keyCode == 38){
         document.activeElement.nextElementSibling.focus();
    }
}
```

but the focus remains on hello. On debugging I saw that the next element (li tag) had `tabindex = -1` which should not be a problem as the focus still can be set programmatically. The only way I was able to set the focus on next element  was to change the `tabindex =0` but that is not technically required.

I have written this [JSFIDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/krs8785/me79ofvx/9/) where you can see that on load i try to set the focus on id =6 but it does not get the focus. But try to to change id to 1 and load. The new element recieves focus.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a `tabindex` on [any element which could be focused](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex).

```
<ul>
    <li tabindex="0">hello</li>
    <li tabindex="0">hi</li>
    <li tabindex="0">bye</li>
    <li tabindex="0">goodbye</li>
</ul>
```